# PHP: generating PDF documents. How to create the template?

Tags: php, pdf-generation

i have found this [tutorial](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/create-pdf-documents-online-with-tcpdf/) to generate a pdf.

In that tutorial there is this kind of code:

```
// list headers
$pdf->CreateTextBox('Quantity', 0, 120, 20, 10, 10, 'B', 'C');
$pdf->CreateTextBox('Product or service', 20, 120, 90, 10, 10, 'B');
$pdf->CreateTextBox('Price', 110, 120, 30, 10, 10, 'B', 'R');
$pdf->CreateTextBox('Amount', 140, 120, 30, 10, 10, 'B', 'R');
```

Should i write this kind of code by hand or there is any app (word processor, vectorial graphics app, what ever) where I can draw the template (size of the cells, colors, etc) of the pdf document first?

I have already created the invoice for the web using HTML/CSS.

Is my first time generating PDF documents so any advise will be wellcome.

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any resources to create PDF templates for you - but you might want to look into [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) - which will let you convert your HTML invoices to PDFs (without needing to generate the PDF yourself).

Comment: +1 for this method. I haven't used this particular tool, but used a similar to solve this problem before, and it works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an HTML+CSS invoice there are [many options available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3178448/264628).

wkhtmltopdf works if you are able to run binary executables on your server. [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) or [mpdf](http://mpdf.bpm1.com/) are good if you need something written entirely in php.